# Controlling AIM-TTI Power supply via C#

Tags: c#, remote-access

I’m working with a Aim-TTi CPX400DP power supply and tasked with using it remotely strictly via Visual Studio using C#. I’ve seen a lot of people on here using LabView and other software but nothing with Visual Studio. In addition upon looking up a manual for this power supply I’m also not seeing any syntax that I could use to call for this power supply in C#. Does anyone have an knowledge or support they could lend for this issue?

I’ve tried downloading NiMax and using it to verify the power supply is connected via USB. It’s denoting the Power supply as COM4. However, when I open up the panel in NiMax there’s no other connections or operations to speak of. I have no way of connecting it and sending or receiving data

Comment: NiMax seems like it is only for National Instruments HW. Do you have any reason to believe that it would work with other manufacturer's equipment?

Comment: When I was given the project I was told it would work. However obviously through testing it has not.

Comment: It's in the manual, chapter "Remote commands", page 27.  Use a terminal emulator like PuTTY to check out the USB connection.  Type "V1?" and press Ctrl+J to send a command, it should respond with the voltage for output 1.  Call the manufacturer for support if nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I should let you know I work for Aim-TTi so I can assist in using your CPX400DP in Visual Studio with C#.

The USB port on a CPX400DP is implemented as a CDC class virtual COM port and can be treated as a standard COM port by any application software.

Below you find a small console application that I created in C#.

Make sure to add "using System.IO.Ports;" which may require you to install the package of the same name (published by Microsoft) from the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.

I would recommend single stepping through this code and then you can see the responses you get in the rx_message string.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace CPX_Console
{
    class Program
    {

        static SerialPort _serialPort;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string tx_message;
            string rx_message;

            _serialPort = new SerialPort();


            // configure the serial port to use the sesired COM port
            // Note, you dont have to configure the baud rate or any of the other default serialPort settings
            _serialPort.PortName = "COM7";

            // open the COM port
            _serialPort.Open();

            // query the CPX identification string
            tx_message = "*IDN?";
            _serialPort.WriteLine(tx_message);

            // get the response
            rx_message = _serialPort.ReadLine();


            // set channel 1 output to 1.23V
            tx_message = "V1 1.23";
            _serialPort.WriteLine(tx_message);


            // enable channel 1
            tx_message = "OP1 1";
            _serialPort.WriteLine(tx_message);

            // query the measured output voltage on channel 1
            tx_message = "V1O?";
            _serialPort.WriteLine(tx_message);

            // get the response
            rx_message = _serialPort.ReadLine();

            // close the COM port
            _serialPort.Close();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for contributing an answer. However, please do not mention off-site help. Stack Overflow is supposed to be a knowledge database, i.e. all answers should stand on their own. The OP can leave a comment when requiring explanation. You can take the [tour] to see what Stack Overflow is about.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it looks like it was located in the manual. By using the V1 for voltage 1 and same thing for amperage, I was able send commands through C#, with both controlling the output and by sending it on and off commands. Only thing that caused me trouble was the serial port, I was connected via USB so it gave me some issues, including that I had to state Mbsession for writing to it. All that aside I was successful and I appreciate the help!!